# How can I update a list like on WhatsApp?

Tags: android

**How can I list updates like WhatsApp?**

I want to update my list automatically when new data is entered into server database, like when a new message comes from the server, the list on chat contact is updated.

Comment: Glad you told us. :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes than what is that? post some code also

Comment: No i didn't try yet, bcause i didn't get any idea about this @Ravi Rupareliya

Comment: [this](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=update%20list%20when%20new%20message%20arrives%20android%20code&oq=update%20list%20when%20new%20message%20arrives%20android%20code&aqs=chrome..69i57.7575j0j7) will give you some idea

Comment: sorry i am not getting any idea from his please suggest to make it fast and i want to do all this work on background

Comment: if you have any webservices which gives you new item by getting id of last item then use `TimerTask` . You can ask me for complete scenario anytime. @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100651/android-talkies

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do is using FCM. When a data is changed in the server, you send a message from the server to your app. In your app interpret the message and load the data again to get the changes.

Comment: i want to do it with without FCM

Comment: Then I guess you have to send request to server every 'n' Second which is not a good idea.

Comment: for that you have to use TimerTask

Comment: is this possible to update list on new notifaction comes

Comment: yes, you can. You have to loadyourdata in your Notification Listener. Please follow the following ling https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-notificationlistenerservice-example.html